# kubectl get -o yaml: is it possible to hide metadata.managedFields?

Tags: kubectl

Using kubectl version 1.18, on microk8s 1.18.3

When getting a resource definition in yaml format. Example  `kubectl get pod/mypod-6f855c5fff-j8mrw -o yaml`. The output contains a section related to [metadata.managedFields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#field-management)

Is there a way to hide that `metadata.managedFields` to shorten the console output?

Below is an example of output to better illustrate the question.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"productpage","service":"productpage"},"name":"productpage","namespace":"bookinfo"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","port":9080}],"selector":{"app":"productpage"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2020-05-28T05:22:41Z"
  labels:
    app: productpage
    service: productpage
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
          f:service: {}
      f:spec:
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":9080,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:selector:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-05-28T05:22:41Z"
  name: productpage
  namespace: bookinfo
  resourceVersion: "121804"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/bookinfo/services/productpage
  uid: feb5a62b-8784-41d2-b104-bf6ebc4a2763
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.152.183.9
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 9080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9080
  selector:
    app: productpage
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Turn out this is a popular request. An issue had been filed [managedFields options are very verbose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90066) on 2020-04-10. So far no solution yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

check out this kubectl plugin: https://github.com/itaysk/kubectl-neat.
it not only removes `managedField` but many other fields users are not interested in.

for example: `kubectl get pod mymod -oyaml | kubectl neat` or `kubectl neat pod mypod -oyaml`

Comment: This is SUPER 'neat` thank you very much. Just a little hiccup with the syntax `kubectl neat pod/mypod-abcd -oyaml` using microk8s: "error while running [kubectl get pod/mypod-abcd -oyaml]: exec: "kubectl": executable file not found in $PATH" This is because the `alias kubectl='microk8s.kubectl'` is not expanded in non-interactive use. `kubectl neat pod/mypod -oyaml | kubectl neat` works OK.

Comment: I'm glad you liked it. Thanks for the feedback, I've created https://github.com/itaysk/kubectl-neat/issues/35 to track this

Answer (score 18):

Kubectl 1.21 doesn't include managed fields by default anymore

> kubectl get will omit managed fields by default now.
> Users could set `--show-managed-fields` to true to show managedFields when the output format is either `json` or `yaml`.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/96878

Comment: This is great news. Any idea if this is also possible to do in the kubernetes API?

Answer (score 11):

For those who like to download yaml and delete unwanted keys try this:

Install `yq` then try(please make sure you get yq version 4.x):

```
cat k8s-config.yaml | yq eval 'del(.status)' - 
   --OR--
kubectl --namespace {namespace} --context {cluster} get pod {podname} | yq ...
```

You may add/join more `yq` to delete more keys. Here is what I did:

```
cat k8s-config.yaml | yq eval 'del(.status)' -  | yq eval 'del (.metadata.managedFields)' - | yq eval 'del (.metadata.annotations)' - | yq eval 'del (.spec.tolerations)' -  | yq eval 'del(.metadata.ownerReferences)' - | yq eval 'del(.metadata.resourceVersion)' - | yq eval 'del(.metadata.uid)' - | yq eval 'del(.metadata.selfLink)' - | yq eval 'del(.metadata.creationTimestamp)' - | yq eval 'del(.metadata.generateName)' -
```

--OR--

```
cat k8s-config.yaml | yq eval 'del(.status)' - \
 | yq eval 'del (.metadata.managedFields)' - \
 | yq eval 'del (.metadata.annotations)' - \
 | yq eval 'del (.spec.tolerations)' - \
 | yq eval 'del(.metadata.ownerReferences)' - \
 | yq eval 'del(.metadata.resourceVersion)' - \
 | yq eval 'del(.metadata.uid)' - \
 | yq eval 'del(.metadata.selfLink)' - \
 | yq eval 'del(.metadata.creationTimestamp)' - \
 | yq eval 'del(.metadata.generateName)' -
```

Another way is to have a `neat()` function on your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` and call it as below:

`neat()` function:

```
neat () {
  yq eval 'del(.items[].metadata.managedFields,
    .metadata,
    .apiVersion,
    .items[].apiVersion,
    .items[].metadata.namespace,
    .items[].kind,
    .items[].status,
    .items[].metadata.annotations,
    .items[].metadata.resourceVersion,
    .items[].metadata.selfLink,.items[].metadata.uid,
    .items[].metadata.creationTimestamp,
    .items[].metadata.ownerReferences)' -
}
```

then:

```
kubectl get pods -o yaml | neat 
cat k8s-config.yaml | neat
```

You may read more on `yq delete` [here](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/delete)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add some basic information about that feature:

**ManagedFields** is a section created by [ServerSideApply](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#server-side-apply) feature. It helps tracking changes in cluster objects by different [managers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/#managers).

If you disable it in the `kube-apiserver` manifests all object created after this change won't have `metadata.managedFields` sections, but it doesn't affect the existing objects.

1. Open the `kube-apiserver` manifest with your favorite text editor:

   ```
   $ sudo vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
   ```
2. Add command line argument to `spec.containers.command`:

   ```
      - --feature-gates=ServerSideApply=false
   ```

`kube-apiserver` will restart immediately.
It usually takes couple of minutes for the `kube-apiserver` to start serving requests again.

You can also disable `ServerSideApply` feature gate on the cluster creation stage.

---

Alternatively, `managedFields` can be [patched](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/#clearing-managedfields) to an empty list for the existing object:

```
$ kubectl patch pod podname -p '{"metadata":{"managedFields":[{}]}}'
```

> This will overwrite the managedFields with a list containing a single empty entry that then results in the managedFields being stripped entirely from the object. Note that just setting the managedFields to an empty list will not reset the field. This is on purpose, so managedFields never get stripped by clients not aware of the field.

Answer (score 3):

Now that `--export` is deprecated, to get the output from your resources in the 'original' format (just cleaned up, without any information you don't want in this situation) you can do the following using `yq` `v4.x`:

```
kubectl get <resource> -n <namespace> <resource-name> -o yaml \
  | yq eval 'del(.metadata.resourceVersion, .metadata.uid, .metadata.annotations, .metadata.creationTimestamp, .metadata.selfLink, .metadata.managedFields)' -
```

Comment: you shouldn't delete annotations, as they are not generated but given and usually part of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

First thing what came to my mind was to just use `stream editor` like [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to just skip this part beggining form `managedFields:` to another specific pattern.

It's bit hardcoded as you would need to specify 2 patterns like `managedFields:` and ending pattern like `name: productpage` but will work for this scenario. If this won't fit you, pleas add more details, how you would like to achieve this.

`sed` command would look like:

```
sed -n '/(Pattern1)/{p; :a; N; /(Pattern2)/!ba; s/.*\n//}; p'
```

For example Ive used Nginx pod:

```
$ kubectl get po nginx -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: 'LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container
      nginx'
  creationTimestamp: "2020-05-29T10:54:18Z"
...
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: nginx
   ...
status:
  conditions:
...
        startedAt: "2020-05-29T10:54:19Z"
  hostIP: 10.154.0.29
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.52.1.6
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.52.1.6
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2020-05-29T10:54:18Z"
```

After using `sed`

```
$ kubectl get po nginx -o yaml | sed -n '/annotations:/{p; :a; N; /hostIP: 10.154.0.29/!ba; s/.*\n//}; p'
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
  hostIP: 10.154.0.29
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.52.1.6
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.52.1.6
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2020-05-29T10:54:18Z"
```

In your case command like:

```
$ kubectl get pod/mypod-6f855c5fff-j8mrw -o yaml | sed -n '/managedFields:/{p; :a; N; /name: productpage/!ba; s/.*\n//}; p'
```

Should give output like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"productpage","service":"productpage"},"name":"productpage","namespace":"bookinfo"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","port":9080}],"selector":{"app":"productpage"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2020-05-28T05:22:41Z"
  labels:
    app: productpage
    service: productpage
  managedFields:
  name: productpage
  namespace: bookinfo
  resourceVersion: "121804"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/bookinfo/services/productpage
  uid: feb5a62b-8784-41d2-b104-bf6ebc4a2763
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.152.183.9
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 9080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9080
  selector:
    app: productpage
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time working on this solution. But this becomes quite `sed` specific. And to workout a correct pattern, I should probably look at the entire output. In that case, all the info I need are already in the screen (albeil a long multilines output). There is no more need to use `sed` to redo a shorter output. I was hoping an option in `kubectl get` itself.